# Why does my pygame window not fit in my 4k(3840x2160) monitor? scale of pygame window: (3000x1500)

Tags: python, pygame, screen-resolution

So I was trying to make a game with python and pygame but I noticed that I couldn't make a high resolution display because when I tried to make a display with more pixels, the pygame window was too big for my **4k (3840x2160)** monitor. I should note that my monitor is connected to an old Dell laptop with a resolution of (1366x768). **But** when I entered this: `print(pygame.display.list_modes())` it told me that I **could** use resolutions up to 4k and not just up to the resolution of my laptop. After a lot of searching and trying I accepted the fact that my game will be low resolution and moved on. As I continued coding the game I wanted to have a pop-up window so I imported **pyautogui** and my pygame window suddenly became much smaller. **BOOM problem solved**. I increased the resolution and I had no problems, my game was now running at a very high **resolution**! I was very confused so I made a very simple pygame program so I could test this and it actually worked. This is **low quality** and **can't fit in my screen**:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((3000, 1500))
font = pygame.font.Font('font.otf', 50)

while True:
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    txt = font.render("hello", True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(txt, (100, 100))
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
```

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfiXG.png)

And this is **high resolution** and **does fit in my screen**:

```
import pygame
import sys
import pyautogui

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((3000, 1500))
font = pygame.font.Font('font.otf', 50)

while True:
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    txt = font.render("hello", True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(txt, (100, 100))
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
```

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd4yX.png)

I don't even need to use **pyautogui**!
Can someone explain this to me?
Thanks

Comment: Just guessing:  Could it be automatic UI scaling, and something in `pyautogui` stops that?  Ref: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3025083/windows-scaling-issues-for-high-dpi-devices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bunch of source diving I believe I have found the solution: pyautogui imports `pyscreeze` for the functions `center, grab, pixel, pixelMatchesColor, screenshot`. On lines 63 to 71 of `pyscreeze/__init__.py` is the following:

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    # On Windows, the monitor scaling can be set to something besides normal 100%.
    # PyScreeze and Pillow needs to account for this to make accurate screenshots.
    # TODO - How does macOS and Linux handle monitor scaling?
    import ctypes
    try:
       ctypes.windll.user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
    except AttributeError:
        pass # Windows XP doesn't support monitor scaling, so just do nothing.
```

The above code calls [SetProcessDPIAware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setprocessdpiaware), which is equivalent to the following:

> System DPI aware. This window does not scale for DPI changes. It will query for the DPI once and use that value for the lifetime of the process. If the DPI changes, the process will not adjust to the new DPI value. It will be automatically scaled up or down by the system when the DPI changes from the system value.

If want to get the same effect without `pyautogui` you can just include the above call to `SetProcessDPIAware` in your code.